Regular languages: words from A that do not contain any word from B as a substring
How to prove, by construction and/or regular closures, that if $A$, $B$ are regular then the language $L$ defined by
$$L=\{w\mid w\in A,\ \not\exists y\in B\ :\ w=xyz\text{ for some }x,z∈Σ^∗\}$$
is also regular?

Not really. I am aware of the general methods but need help with this specific language

Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See here for a short introduction.

What have you tried?

Please choose a more descriptive title, so people can have an idea what they will find when visiting this page, and so people with the same question can find this page via search.  There are probably hundreds of questions here that the current title could plausibly apply to.

Your language is $A$ intersected with
$$\{w\mid \not\exists y\in B\ :\ w=xyz\text{ for some }x,z∈Σ^∗\},$$ i.e., the complement of
$$\{w\mid\exists y\in B\ :\ w=xyz\text{ for some }x,z∈Σ^∗\}$$
which is $$\overline{\Sigma^* B \Sigma^*},$$
so
$$L=A\cap \overline{\Sigma^* B \Sigma^*}$$
which is regular by the usual closure properties of regular languages.

It is the same as A-sigmaBsigma,right?

@user169627 Yes, it is.

Appreciate the help!
